# spynner how i can click login button?

Tags: python, authentication, spynner

I want to get acces to vk.com - all what I do is:

```
>>> import spynner as s
>>> b = s.Browser()
>>> b.load('http://vk.com')
True
>>> b.wk_fill('input[#name=email]', 'my@mail.ru')
>>> b.wk_fill('input[name=pass]', 'my_secret_password')
>>> b.create_webview()
>>> b.show()
```

It shows me https://picasaweb.google.com/108465638371111457481/SpynnerExperiments#5776810930419210290
And how after that I can click the login button via spynner?

Full traceback and my attempts you can see here: http://dumpz.org/245555/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me (using [this spynnner](https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner)):

```
import spynner
b = spynner.Browser()
b.show()
b.load('http://vk.com')
b.wk_fill('input[name=email]', 'my@mail.ru')
b.wk_fill('input[name=pass]', 'my_secret_password')
b.click("#quick_login_button")
b.browse() # this way we see wha's going on
```